# Dungeons spawn under villages, myth or fact?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I heard that dungeons spawn under villages in Minecraft bedrock edition, is this true or is this just a myth? Also if the data is available and they do spawn under villages what is the chance of it happening?

Comment: I'll leave the chance of it happening to someone much smarter than myself because there's a lot to take into account with the mathematics on it. I can say though that in BE there's a 2/3 chance for a village to be generated within 500 blocks of the initial world spawn point.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dungeons ***can*** spawn under villages in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).

---

According to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dungeon), dungeons can spawn underground, anywhere above sea level:

> In Bedrock Edition, dungeons can generate as underground structures above sea level.

With this, there are some rules that are followed as dungeons are generated:

> For each chunk, 8 attempts are made to generate a dungeon; it is possible, though unlikely, for multiple attempts to succeed. For each attempt, a location and size (an open area with a width and length of 7, 9, or 11 and a height of 6) is chosen. The attempt succeeds if the following conditions are met:
>
> - The floor area (including under the walls) of the potential dungeon must be entirely solid.
> - The ceiling area (including over the walls) of the potential dungeon must be entirely solid. The ceiling blocks may be gravity-affected such as gravel or sand, which fall if disturbed by the player.
> - The walls of the potential dungeon must have 1–5 openings (2-high air blocks) at floor level.

As a result, since dungeons can occur in any biome, anywhere above sea level, it is possible for dungeons to be generated under villages.

Also, in version 1.16 using the seed `1363703574` will generate a dungeon directly under a village (feel free to verify, it no longer works in 1.17):

Comment: Can I ask when you started playing @Taco タコス?

Comment: @MikeZ. I've been playing creative since around the time it was released for XBOX 360, only got in-depth with it around a year ago though.